# Meaning of exclamation before dot

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've seen somewhere written in the code `fixture.componentInstance.dataSource!.data = [];`

I want to know the meaning of `dataSource!.data`

I know about the meaning of question mark(?) before dot(.) like `key1?.key2` but an Exclamation(!) before dot(.) `!.` expression makes me curious.

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: **"Non-null assertion operator"**
It tells the compiler that `fixture.componentInstance.dataSource` is not null.

It's a typescript 2.0 feature.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator

Answer (score 2):

It's called the Non-null Assertion Operator

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-

It removes `null` and `undefined`, allowing you to assert that you know there will be a value. Usually this is a code smell, something that should give you pause to consider other methods so that you can avoid using it. Type narrowing would be preferred. But in some specific instances, this operator can be a useful tool.